# How can I get a reference of a powerpoint presentation I can use in python?

Tags: python, vba, powerpoint

So I'm trying to open a ppt application, and switch slides, and end the ppt using python.

I don't know how to call a macro from within python either. I've seen people use win32.client for it, but I'm on a mac. Is there any way for me to do these things and get a reference of the Presentation object within Python?

I've figured out the VBA macros (or so I think):

```
//starting a slideshow
Sub run()
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run
End Sub

//for next slide
Sub next()
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. I'm relatively new to coding and really grasping at straws at this point, Thanks a ton!

I tried looking up a bunch of places:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/PowerPoint/StartingaSlideShow.htm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0PknGechXI

They both use VBA or the win32 client. I don't mind creating the macros' code for VBA, but I dont know how to call a piece of macro code on a running PPT.

Answer (score 0):

Can I introduce you to [python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

It's a Python 3 library that I think will do what you want. (I am a fellow Mac user and have done a lot of work with this package.)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I find that python-pptx is designed more for creating a powerpoint presentation, but I want to be able to control a slideshow when it is actively presenting. I couldn't find any such commands in the documentation for python-pptx.

Comment: Yes, you're right: Sorry I didn't notice you wanted to manipulate the PowerPoint UI. (I'm too focused on the .pptx file format.O